# One big list to specific dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to convert list to Dict. i tried many solutions but can't find way to do exactly like this
python dict is one of the best things in python so i need Dict
***I have one big list like this***

```
[{
    '1': {
        '1.1': '',
        '1.2': '',
        '1.3': False
    }
}, {
    '2': {
        '2.1': False
    }
}, {
    '3': {
        '3.1': [100, 91, 100, 100],
        '3.2': 5,
        '3.3': True,
        '3.5': ['Page has no headings', 'This form element has no label.', 'This link has no text inside it.', 'This link text is uninformative.'],
        '3.6': 4
    }
}, {
    '4': {
        '4.1': False,
        '4.2': False,
        '4.3': True
    }
}, {
    '5': {
        '5.1': True,
        '5.2': '"2021-12-14 19:00:42"',
        '5.3': True
    }
}]
```

***I only want Dict like this***

```
final_result ={
                '1': {
                '1.1': '',
                '1.2': '',
                '1.3': False
                 }
            '2': {
                '2.1': False
               }
            '3': {
                '3.1': [100, 91, 100, 100],
                '3.2': 5,
                '3.3': True,
                '3.5': ['Page has no headings', 'This form element has no label.', 'This link has no text inside it.', 'This link text is uninformative.'],
                '3.6': 4
            }
            '4': {
                '4.1': False,
                '4.2': False,
                '4.3': True
            }
            '5': {
                '5.1': True,
                '5.2': '"2021-12-14 19:00:42"',
                '5.3': True
            }
        }
```

I tried some ways but I'm having a bad day so can't get the solution

thanx

Comment: i want one dict result containing all other not list @Rawing

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop retrieving data updating a result dictionary would be enough:

```
l = yourlist
res = {}
for e in l:
  res.update(e)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/Ngmo/0)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
dictionary = {}
for item in lst:
    for key in item:
        dictionary[key] = item[key]
```

It should output something like this:

```
{'1': {...}, '2': {...}, ... }
```

Comment: gives me :  `list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: That is not what you have specified in your own example? But it is easy to fix, just change the inner loop to `dictionary[int(key)] =`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to join all the dicts together

```
your_list = ...
def join(d1, d2):
  z = d1.copy()
  z.update(d2)
  return z

reduce(join, your_list, {})
```

Comment: you should not use reduce for mutable operations.

Comment: that is what the d1.copy() is for... Still, your way is better :)

Comment: then you are avoiding the mutable state by creating a overhead of memory. I was only pointing out that you should not, not that you actually can`t

Comment: Overhead of memory is an exaggeration.  This is how immutability works - by creating a new object instead of mutating an existing one.